# How to structure code for Activitys in a tabhost and actionbars

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-activity

I want to have a few pages under a tabhost. The pages with the tabs, are accessed on about page 2/3 after application start. I am confused in how to link to the first page of the tabhost (from a page without a tabhost)

Each tab in the tabhost is a separate activity.

So when it's time to send user to a page in the tabhost, do I start the Tabhost activity (from extends TabActivity), create the tabhost, then... somehow choose which page in the tab to load? like tabhost.myTab.trigger.start(); INSTEAD of just loading one of the tabs activities directly..

So therefore anytime you leave the tabhost, and come back to it , you are recreating it, is this the correct way to structure things?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TabHost method is considered a pretty old way of creating tabs within your Android application. This is especially so if you're placing Activities within those tabs.

A modern Android application uses Fragments, and uses the Action Bar framework to place those Fragments within tabs.

This can be done easily from your main Activity by using

```
getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

This has several advantages. It means your Fragments can be placed inside of a ViewPager (so the user can swipe between them). It also means that your tabs will adapt to the device they're running on. (On a phone they may appear below the Action Bar, but on a tablet they actually become part of the Action Bar).

Depending on your implementation, this can be done is such a way that navigating between tabs does not cause the Fragments to be recreated (if that's what you're after).

A detailed guide on how to implement Action Bar Tabs can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs)

If backwards compatibility is a concern, then check out the amazing [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand the behavior you are trying to accomplish.

Though, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, i would recommend you to install the ActionBarSherlock demo apps[1](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) to check if the desired behavior is already implemented as one of the library examples. If it's already done, then you can go to the [github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) project to take a look at the source code, learn how it's done, and contribute with it.

> Action Bar Sherlock demos
>
> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos&hl=en
>
> Action Bar Sherlock Fragment demos
>
> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionbarsherlock.sample.fragments&hl=en